# How to hide text in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to hide words in a string via their position so reg ex will not work. Is there a easy way as I do not have access to the template files so I can not alter span wrapping or add classes ect to the document.

I would like to hide the "by Salutions" text. This text will change to who the author is so as I said regular expressions will not work, but the position of the words will be identical.

Here is a snippet in question.

```
<p class="p-meta"><span>In <a href="http://www.domain here" title="View all posts in: &ldquo;People&rdquo;"> People</a> by Salutions</span><span><time class="entry-date" datetime="2014-12-05T13:01:18+00:00">December 5, 2014</time></span></p>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: "text will change to who the author is so as I said regular expressions will not work" that's exactly what regular expressions are good at

Comment: I will have over 30 different names posting articles, also the names will change frequently that's why I was thinking against reg ex.

Comment: @OP - That makes no sense, you don't need to specify each author, regular expressions have wildcards for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always at same index, you can use:

```
$('p.p-meta span:first').contents().eq(2).remove();
```

### -DEMO-

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to adding dynamically an author's name:

```
<p class="p-meta">
    <span>In 
        <a href="http://www.domain here" title="View all posts in: &ldquo;People&rdquo;"> 
            People
        </a> by <span id="owner"></span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <time class="entry-date" datetime="2014-12-05T13:01:18+00:00">
            December 5, 2014</time>
    </span>
</p>
```

By using this function, the author's name would be added to that HTML:

```
function addOwner(owner) {
    $( '#owner' ).text( owner );
}
```

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnhetvpb/).